# What is the best design for a class that is responsible for CRUD operations on the database?

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture

I want to create a class `User` that will manipulate data on the `user` table in my database. But I don't know if I should make it a Singleton or just bundle a bunch of static methods.

```java
class UserSingleton {
    private static instance;

    private UserSingleton() {
        // stablish connection and prepare statements
    }

    public static getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new UserSingleton();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public void create() {};
    public void delete() {};
    // and so on...
}

class UserStatic {
    public static initialize() {
         // Stablish connection and prepare statements. 
         // These properties would be static.
    }

    public static void create() {};
    public static void delete() {};
    // and so on...
}
```

I really don't know what would be the best approach here or the pros and cons of each of them. While the singleton class seems more elegant and cool, the static class API would be easier to use since I don't have to instantiate an object. Also it resembles me of mongoose, where such methods are static, e.g: `Model.create()`, `Model.findById()`, and so on...

What do you think? Or I should do it in a completely different manner? Some context about the app:

- It's a small/medium desktop app made with JavaFX
- The database is SQLite
- Tests aren't a priority (some people may point out that Singleton is bad because it makes testing harder)

Comment: The best approach isn't to write them at all but instead to use tools that do it for you (such as Spring Data and/or JPA). (Also, make sure not to conflate code-enforced singletons that use `static` anything with functional singletons like Spring/CDI singletons where the class is just an ordinary class but the container only makes one copy per run. The latter is still easy to test and manage.)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at JPA, Spring Data with eclipselink as implementation or Hibernate. If it is just for educational purpouses have a look at the spring orm implementaions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Avoid singletons [at any cost](https://www.yegor256.com/2016/06/27/singletons-must-die.html)
2. You need to specify your API with interfaces.
   It appears that you have `Users` and `User` which could be defined like that

```java
interface User {
    long id();
    String name();
}
interface Users {
    Iterable<User> iterate();
    User create(String name);
    void delete(User user);
    Optional<User> findById(long id);
}
```

3. Implement these interfaces with plain `jdbc` or with help of a library such as [jOOQ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ) or [jcabi-jdbc](https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-jdbc)
4. Avoid [ORM](https://www.yegor256.com/2014/12/01/orm-offensive-anti-pattern.html) and thinking about your business task in terms of databases and SQL. Use [OOP](https://www.yegor256.com/2014/11/20/seven-virtues-of-good-object.html) tactics to design your objects and how they work with each other.